# Behavior of Ada.Strings.Fixed.Index_Non_Blank

Tags: string, ada

I was thinking that, quite logically according to its name, this function will return the index of the 1st character not being whitespace, that is, among others, not being a space or a tabulation.

However, when testing it on some strings, and also when looking at its implementation (file *a-strsea.adb* for `GNAT 4.7.4`), I realized that this function returns in fact the index of the 1st character not being an ordinary space (`ASCII 32`). This is in my opinion not consistent with what its name could let suppose.

So, where could I find the expected behaviour of this function (apart from looking at the code)? Indeed, in the `AARM` for `Ada 2012`, I only found the prototypes, without any semantic information.

Answer (score 6):

I agree that the use of the word "Blank" is inappropriate. Elsewhere, the standard defines a "blank" as "a space or a horizontal tabulation character".

The AARM does define the behavior of `Ada.Strings.Fixed.Index_Non_Blank`:

```
function Index_Non_Blank (Source : in String;
                          From : in Positive;
                          Going : in Direction := Forward)
    return Natural;
```

> Returns `Index (Source, Maps.To_Set(Space), From, Outside, Going);`

```
function Index_Non_Blank (Source : in String;
                          Going : in Direction := Forward)
    return Natural;
```

> Returns `Index(Source, Maps.To_Set(Space), Outside, Going)`

where `Space` is `Ada.Characters.Latin_1.Space`, defined as `' '`.

The fact that the standard shows the specification of the `Ada.Strings.Fixed` index without commentary, followed by the descriptions of the effects of the declared subprograms, might be confusing. Just search the document for `Index_Non_Blank`, and don't assume all the information about it will be in one place.